# CSS background color for child container extending till parent container

Tags: html, css

Need background color for child container extending till width of view point.  Properties needed should be applied to child container only.

I tried giving huge border to child container till parent container, but it did not work in high resolution screens.

Background color should applied only to the area of text.

```css
.outer{
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 420px;
}
.inner{
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Need background color for child container extending till width of view point. properties needed have to be given only within child container. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link to better understand the scenario:

https://jsfiddle.net/5qp1a3um/

Comment: Can you remove the fixed width?

Comment: Child container width is fixed and have margins on left and right ends. Basically the page content is placed in inner container itself.

Comment: You want the child container to be the full size of the parent but have the text constrained to a 200X300 square?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a wrapper to contain the desired color like this:

```css
.bg-wrapper{
    background: #54BCDF; /*change to desired color*/
}
.outer {
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">Need background color for child container extending till width of view point. properties needed have to be given only within child container.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bearing in mind that you can only change the css of child container you can try with this modification of the answer of Rick to extend the `background`:

```css
.outer{
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 420px;
}
.inner{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner:before {
  content: '';
  background:  #54BCDF; /*change to desired color*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Need background color for child container extending till width of view point. properties needed have to be given only within child container. 
  </div>
</div>
```

But to center `.outer` I'm afraid that you'll have to add the style `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that the background color is just for the content.

Comment: @Sandeep can you add a link to an image to exactly  see what you want to achieve?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAdhUrKQ9UqQklCN0dfOHVleHc/view?usp=sharing

Need background like extended content div in attached image.

Answer (score 2):

Set the parent's position to relative:

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then create a pseudo-element on the child, which covers the extent of the parent (width and height 100%).

Give it a negative z-index so its background won't hide the content:

```
.inner:before {
  content: '';
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/f0nnz1se/)

---

*Update based on the fact that you can't style the parent*

Set the child's position to relative:

```
.inner {
  position: relative;
}
```

The pseudo-element's width should now be 100% plus the difference between the child's and parent's widths.

You'll need to move the pseudo-element left to account for the child's left margin:

```
.inner:before {
  content: '';
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 220px);  /* parent's width - child's width = 220 */
  left: -100px;               /* account for left margin */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/f0nnz1se/2/)

Comment: In this case, the CSS properties for the parent container cannot be edited. Any change needed to be rendered from child container CSS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but I gave it a shot.

In the CSS if you change the margin to padding, then any background color on the child element will extend to the parent. background color is includes the padding but not the margin.

I also had to bump up the width of the child 20px for it to fill properly.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qp1a3um/1/

```
.inner{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding instead of margin, that's the right way to do it.

```
padding: 0 100px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qp1a3um/2/